# Which materials make a good tire?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, questions, present-tense

Please, is this poster title right? (the poster is about raw materials composing a tire)

> Which materials make a good tire?

Or I should better write:

> Which materials are in a good tire?

Or

> What materials make a good tire?

Comment: The usual collocation is **make for**.   *What qualities make for a good girlfriend/boyfriend?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both phrases are grammatically correct, but the first conveys the intent better; there are materials that are found in a good tire, which don't contribute to its quality - they are the same as in a bad tire. The *make* here has a special purpose - it's not just about "are used in production", it's "cause that the tire is good."

As for *which* vs *what* - first implies picking from a list, the other is a free choice. If you provide a list of materials, and ask to pick the correct ones, *which* is the correct word. If you're asking an open question, don't sweat it - the list is implied, both words work okay.